# SQL query improved performance needed (1 table)

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, i've got a query (which i use as a Stored Procedure) in SQL Server 2008 R2. 
It works, but i cannot believe there isn't a more efficient way.

The data is in a table 'ServiceInstance'. This is one, completely flat table containing **16** 'instances' per IPAddress, each of them having a unique TCPPort for that IPAddress.

The columns 'isRestarting' and 'isInuse' are not really important to this system; 
both when 'isRestarting' or 'isInUse' are *True*, the 'IsAvailable' is *False*

The column 'CPUId' is; each server has 4 CPUs - and the Delhpi application i'm running can only have 1 application on a CPU at the same time. So, when CPU #1 on Server with IP '192.168.4.151' is in use, that CPUId on that IP is not allowed to be returned from the query. (There are 16 instances on one server with 4 cores)

[image: The table with data])

So, the SP must do the following:

Get an available instance, which must comply to:

- The SP should always return 1 row.

  - This is a low prio for me atm - i can rerun the SP if needed
- The ServerInstance' IsEnabled must be true
- **When the ServerInstance is returned, it must be set to 'IsAvailable' = False so it won't be picked again until work is done (reset is done by my application logic)**
- None of the same CPUId on that IP must be 'IsAvailable = False'

  - This makes sure the CPU # on that server is free
- The ServerInstance which hasn't been used the longest is preferred.

  - Because I have a large pool and want to load balance traffic
- The 'found' ServerInstance is to be updated immediately.

  - The 'LastRequestDate' should be stamped
  - The 'IsInuse' set to True
  - The 'IsAvailable' set to **False**

So. With this information I've created this monster:

```
 UPDATE top(1) ServiceInstance 
    SET 
        LastRequestDate=GETDATE()
        ,IsInUse=1 
        ,IsAvailable=0
    OUTPUT 
        inserted.ServiceInstanceId,
        inserted.IpAddress,
        inserted.TcpPort,
        inserted.LastRequestDate,
        inserted.IsInUse
    WHERE 
    ServiceInstanceId IN
    (
    SELECT Top (1) ServiceInstanceId FROM ServiceInstance
    WHERE
    (ServiceInstance.IsAvailable = 1 AND ServiceInstance.IsEnabled = 1)
    AND ServiceInstanceId NOT IN
        (
        SELECT NGI1.ServiceInstanceId
        FROM 
            (SELECT CpuId,IpAddress 
            FROM [ServiceInstance] NGI
            WHERE IsInUse=1) a
            INNER JOIN ServiceInstance AS NGI1 ON a.IpAddress = NGI1.IpAddress AND a.CpuId = NGI1.CpuId
        )
    ORDER BY LastRequestDate ASC
    )
```

However, I feel this cannot be the most efficient way to go about things.
This Query is supposed to be running ~10 times per second on peek hours and thus currently putting some heavy CPU pressure on my SQL Server.

Any tips welcome! I feel i should be able to use PARTITION OVER or join to my own table, but I cannot seem to create it successfully...!

Ok, so, the table structure is as following:

- ServiceInstanceId INT NOT NULL
- IPAddres varchar(20) NOT NULL
- TCPPort varchar(5) NOT NULL
- LastRequestDate DateTime NOT NULL
- IsEnabled BIT NOT NULL
- IsAvailable BIT NOT NULL
- IsRestarting BIT NOT NULL
- IsInuse BIT NOT NULL
- CPU INT NOT NULL

On this moment, I have no indexes. This because the table is mutated a lot (every time a ServerInstance is 'used' the table mutates 3 or 4 times 
(1= *use*, 2 = *restart after use*, 3= set *IsAvailable*, 4= *restart on failure*)
My guess was that, if i made Indexes, these would have to be updated every mutation. Not sure but i felt like it would decrease performance :)

Exec plan:
[image: Execution plan for my query:]

IMPORTANT ADDITION after some loadtests:

I really needed to use `Exec @RC =sp_getapplock @Resource='MyLock', @LockMode='Exclusive', @LockOwner='Transaction', @LockTimeout = 1000` For this StoredProcedure. Doesn't work well without it!

Comment: You have error in your query: SET IsAvailable=0 - must be 1, if you want The 'IsAvailable' set to True

Comment: No, as soon as the 'ServerInstance' is picked up from the pool, it is unavailable. My application logic will set it 'Available' when done :). Edit: ive update my post with this information, thanks

Comment: Is `[NhgDocV40].[dbo].[ServiceInstance]` different from `ServiceInstance`? In the second alinea you mean 16 instances right? And in the last bullet you mean `The 'IsAvailable' set to False`?

Comment: You are so right and sharp! I Edited the post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH UnAvailableCpus AS (
    SELECT IpAddress
          ,CpuId
    FROM ServiceInstance
    WHERE IsAvailable = 0
    GROUP BY IpAddress
            ,CpuId
)
,AvailableInstances AS (
    SELECT ServiceInstanceId
          ,LastRequestDate
    FROM ServiceInstance
         LEFT JOIN UnavailableCpus
             ON UnavailableCpus.IpAddress = ServiceInstance.IpAddress
                AND UnavailableCpus.CpuId = ServiceInstance.CpuId
    WHERE ServiceInstance.IsAvailable = 1 
          AND ServiceInstance.IsEnabled = 1
          AND UnavailableCpus.IpAddress IS NULL
)
,PreferredInstance AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 ServiceInstanceId
    FROM AvailableInstances
    ORDER BY LastRequestDate
)
UPDATE ServiceInstance 
SET 
    LastRequestDate=GETDATE()
   ,IsInUse=1 
   ,IsAvailable=0
OUTPUT 
   inserted.ServiceInstanceId
  ,inserted.IpAddress
  ,inserted.TcpPort
  ,inserted.LastRequestDate
  ,inserted.IsInUse
WHERE ServiceInstanceId IN (SELECT ServiceInstanceId FROM PreferredInstance)
```

Comment: First tests i've been running this T SQL works like a charm! Should i be indexing a column, when i have ~36 IpAddresses  (36 * 16 = 576 records) ?

Comment: 576 records should only be 3-4 pages. Don't think an index will make any significant difference

Answer (score 1):

It may be related with the structure of the table (if you post it we can further elaborate).

Best guess is to create indexes for any column used for joins, if not already done:

- CpuId
- IpAddress
- IsInUse

Also not bad to create indexes for columns used for where conditions:

- IsAvailable
- IsEnabled

Anyway, this that you present is a "planning" algorithm for process execution of something like a distributed operating system. This kind of algorithms are always programmed to have all information presistent in memory, and the execution of the planning (selecting which executes what and where) to be compiled to native code. In the case of the Linux kernel, for example, in C++. If you delegate the info to a database engine, and the planning to a three level nested SQL, performance is going to be bad. Databases are better suited for processing large quantities of information for a result, or serving a lot of clients quering information at the same time, or logging and storing a lot of data quickly.

Maybe you should try to program everything in Delphi, with an object oriented approach, without database and SQL.

Comment: Hmm, this SUM() is a nice approach. Im gonna try and play with that

Comment: I totally agree. Unfortunately this code is to be implemented in a webfarm. Node 1 of the farm does not know about node 2 memory and table status. Thanks for the info though, I like learning about these processes

Comment: Ok, but all nodes are rellying in a central govern node: the database. Maybe you can make your own program to control them as a central node. Centralised and decentralised multi node operation systems is a complex matter anyway, that is going to be a lot of more work that simply using the database. Maybe look for different design approachs on distributed operating systems: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_operating_system#Distributed_computing_models

Answer (score 0):

Try this query to replace your retrieval query:

```
select top 1 tbl.serviceinstanceid from
(select 
 ipaddress, 
 cpuid, 
 sum(case when isavailable = 1 then 1 else 0 end) 
 over (partition by ipaddress, cpuid order by ipaddress, cpuid) s
 from tbl
 where isenabled = 1
) t
inner join serviceinstance tbl on tbl.ipaddress = t.ipaddress and tbl.cpuid = t.cpuid
where t.s = 4
and tbl.isinuse = 0
order by lastrequestdate
```

Assumptions: The 4 fields with 1 and 0 values are of type `bit`.

Breakdown:

- Sum is used to check how many of the 4 CPUIDs per IP Address are available. We are only interested in those where sum = 4.
- All must be enabled.
- Must not be in use when selecting.
- Must be the one with minimum value for last request date.

Comment: No problem. Does my query retrieve the results that you expect? I wasn't very clear on the requirement.